# Form and Jquery code not working. Greying out submit button

Tags: jquery, forms, button, submit

I have a subscription form in HTML that uses (or should use) a jquery code to grey out the SUBMIT button until the field **name** has been filled out.

However, it is not working...

Any clue of what is wrong? Here is the code:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var $submit = $("input[type=submit]");
if ( $(".subName").length > 0 ) {
   $submit.attr("disabled","disabled");
} else {
   $submit.removeAttr("disabled");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post" id="subscribe" name="subscribe">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="subscribe">
<label>NAME:</label>
<input type="text" name="name" class="subName" id="sub_first_name">
<label>EMAIL:</label>
<input type="text" name="email" class="subEmail" id="sub_email">
<input type="submit" name="button" value="Subscribe" />
</form>
</body>
```

Thanks!

-------------------------- EDIT

```
<form action="" method="post" id="subscribe" name="subscribe">
<label>NAME:</label>
<input type="text" name="name" class="subName" id="sub_first_name">
<label>EMAIL:</label>
<input type="text" name="email" class="subEmail" id="sub_email">
<input type="submit" name="button" value="Subscribe" />
</form>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $submit = $("input[type=submit]");
    $('.subName').on('change', function() {
        if ( ! $(".subName").val().length ) {
           $submit.attr("disabled","disabled");
        } else {
           $submit.removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

But still not working :(

Comment: Yes.. you are only checking it when the page loads..  You should bind it to an event

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $submit = $("input[type=submit]");
    $('.subName').on('change keyup', function() {
        if ( !$(this).val().length ) {
           $submit.attr("disabled","disabled");
        } else {
           $submit.removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It should be $(".subName").val().length. $(".subName").length will be the number of elements matching the selector, i.e having the class "subName"

Comment: Nice to finally be quicker than someone else on here :).

Comment: If you want the greying out of the button to be more "responsive", you could use $('.subName').on('change, keyup'), function(){...} and it will update with every keystroke (change will only trigger when focus leaves the field I think). Also, it would be better maybe to select by id instead of class: $('#sub_first_name').on()...

Comment: Would you mind writing that as an answer with the code? Or in a fiddle?

Comment: Couldn't check it, jsfiddle.net seems to be down. However, I applied your suggestion (see updated question) but it doesn't work so far... Any advice? Thanks!

Comment: any js error in console?
you'll also need to make the button disabled on pageload via html attribute or adding $('.subName').trigger('change') in the ready.
make sure .on is bound to 'change keyup' and not 'change' only or it will only fire on field blur

Comment: In console I get: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input "

Answer (score 0):

Besides binding it to an event, do you also include jQuery in your header? For example like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
```